# How to put border around textview?

Tags: android, textview, border

border.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/ res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000"/>

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding android:left="10dp"
             android:top="5dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="5dp"/>

     </shape>
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

I am unable to get the border in the textview using the above code. The constraint layout width and height are set to match_parent.

Comment: set width and height to wrap content. and remove constraints from TextView

Comment: remove selector and padding from your border.xml

Comment: @ZakiPathan It doesn't  work. Tried it.

Comment: @VivekMishra Removing selector and padding doesn't work. If not there where should i include the padding ?

Comment: define shape with your shape tag like this `android:shape="rectangle"`

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks. I got my mistake there is a space before res in shape tag !

Comment: @VivekMishra Why using selector doesn't show the border ?

Comment: selector is not meant for this purpose. It is for showing different color or image when selecting an item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're wrong in border.xml file.

Try doing a test with this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

if it works it means that something wrong in the syntax. (maybe badly used the selector)

Comment: Thanks. I got my mistake there is a space before res in shape tag !